# Match an email address which is before a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have a regex to match email addresses in javascript. Lets see an example:

```
var email  = "aaa@bbb.com (A,B); ccc@ddd.com (C,D); eee@fff.com (E,F);";
var emails = email.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
```

This will return me all the emails in the var emails.

Now, I have a string:

```
var initials = "(A,B)";
```

And I would like to get only the email before the initials value;

If the var initials is "(A,B)", then I would like to get only the aaa@bbb.com email address.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: you can split your `email` string by `;` and filtering every element with `findString(initials)`

Comment: @loldop, thanks, but I don't think it's a good idea in my case.

Comment: your example not represent why you want use regular expression. do you have delimiter between every (mail and initials)? you maybe want to make a hash-array from you string

Comment: @loldop. In fact, I would like to find the email which corresponds to the given initials. As I say, if i have (A,B), i would like to get the aaa@bbb.com email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***JavaScript:***

```
var input = "aaa@bbb.com (A,B); ccc@ddd.com (C,D); eee@fff.com (E,F);";
var initials = "(A,B)";
var email = input.match(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)(?=\\s*" + initials.replace(/([()])/g, "\\$1") + ")"))[0];
print(email);
```

***Output:***

```
aaa@bbb.com
```

*Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/84I8O).*

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you ! ! ! ! !  Excellent, I am trying to implement this since 3 days. Great answer.

Answer (score -1):

Whether you have something like this "example@mail.com(A,B)" or like this "(A,B)example@mail.com", all you have to do is have the first and last part of the only capture letters. So the (A,B) should be automatically excluded for he capture of the regex.

If that is not the issue you can always grab the text returned by the regular expression and use replace to change the (A,B) to nothing, just like this:

```
var regexresult=str.replace("(A,B)","");
```

That code will remove the string if it's present, otherwise it will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you Raul, but the problem is different in my case. In fact, I know the initials and with them, I woul like to get the email just before. The iitials are allways at the end of the email address, with a space before.